# There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-...'

Tags: c#, .net, maui, servicestack, maui-blazor

I'm struggeling building my .NET MAUI Blazor App. It has worked before, but now I'm getting these errors:

[image]

I've searched for hours, but can't seem to fix this. Does someone knows how I can get my App running again?

**UPDATE:**

Here you can find my .csproj file. I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio Community 17.8.1

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->

        <!-- Note for MacCatalyst:
            The default runtime is maccatalyst-x64, except in Release config, in which case the default is maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64.
            When specifying both architectures, use the plural <RuntimeIdentifiers> instead of the singular <RuntimeIdentifier>.
            The Mac App Store will NOT accept apps with ONLY maccatalyst-arm64 indicated;
            either BOTH runtimes must be indicated or ONLY macatalyst-x64. -->
        <!-- For example: <RuntimeIdentifiers>maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> -->

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>Erp.Mobile.App</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <EnableDefaultCssItems>false</EnableDefaultCssItems>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>TW</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.tw.erp.mobile.app</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">24.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationTitle>TW</ApplicationTitle>
      <ApplicationId>com.tw.erp.mobile.app</ApplicationId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-maccatalyst|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationTitle>TW</ApplicationTitle>
      <ApplicationId>com.tw.erp.mobile.app</ApplicationId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationTitle>TW</ApplicationTitle>
      <ApplicationId>com.tw.erp.mobile.app</ApplicationId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-maccatalyst|AnyCPU'">
      <ApplicationTitle>TW</ApplicationTitle>
      <ApplicationId>com.tw.erp.mobile.app</ApplicationId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\tw_icon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\tw_icon.svg" Color="#231f20" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\tw_splash.svg" Color="#231f20" BaseSize="256,256" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\open-iconic\FONT-LICENSE" />
      <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\open-iconic\font\fonts\open-iconic.svg" />
      <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\open-iconic\ICON-LICENSE" />
      <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\open-iconic\README.md" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Resources\AppIcon\tw_icon.svg" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Splash\tw_splash.svg" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text" Version="8.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="wwwroot\css\open-iconic\FONT-LICENSE" />
      <None Include="wwwroot\css\open-iconic\font\fonts\open-iconic.svg" />
      <None Include="wwwroot\css\open-iconic\ICON-LICENSE" />
      <None Include="wwwroot\css\open-iconic\README.md" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Erp.Entity\Erp.Entity.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Resources\Images\" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found what was wrong. I'm using ServiceStack.Net inside my project and was referencing the wrong nuget packages

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text" Version="8.0.0" />
```

By removing those references and adding this nuget package I've fixed the errors...

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Blazor" Version="8.0.0" />
```

I hope this is usefull for other members using StackOverflow.